# Makefile not Windows compatible?

Tags: python, makefile, pyqt, pyqt4, python-sip

I'm attempting to install the Pyforms library, so I attempted to install PyQt4 as a dependency. PyQt4 has SIP as a dependency, so I went and attempted to build that file from scratch as well (when installed via Pip, I was informed that sipconfig.py did not exist, for some reason? Even so, I'd still run into this problem eventually).

Unfortunately, Microsoft Visual Studio doesn't seem to like the Makefile automatically generated by SIP. When I attempt to run nmake, I get countless errors. Is there something I can do here, or is it impossible for me to go on? (Alternatively, supply me with a simple PyQt4/SIP binary installer). I'm afraid that I'm rather out of my depth.

Here are the errors given when I attempt to run NMAKE:

```
NMAKE : warning U4001: command file can be invoked only from command line
NMAKE : warning U4001: command file can be invoked only from command line
NMAKE : warning U4001: command file can be invoked only from command line
NMAKE : warning U4001: command file can be invoked only from command line
NMAKE : warning U4001: command file can be invoked only from command line
NMAKE : warning U4001: command file can be invoked only from command line
NMAKE : warning U4001: command file can be invoked only from command line
NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'all:'
```

And these are the contents of the Makefile:

```
all:
    cd sipgen
    $(MAKE)
    @cd ..
    cd siplib
    $(MAKE)
    @cd ..

install:
    cd sipgen
    $(MAKE) install
    @cd ..
    cd siplib
    $(MAKE) install
    @cd ..
    @if not exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages" mkdir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages"
    copy /y sipconfig.py "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\sipconfig.py"
    copy /y C:\Users\***\Downloads\sip-4.19.3\sip-4.19.3\sipdistutils.py "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\sipdistutils.py"

clean:
    cd sipgen
    $(MAKE) clean
    @cd ..
    cd siplib
    $(MAKE) clean
    @cd ..
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to build PyQt on Windows, there's an installer.

Comment: Are you running the commands from a Visual Studio command prompt?